# Getting enum names (e.g. CV_32FC1) of OpenCV image types?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, enums, image-formats

In the C++ interface to OpenCV, it seems easy enough to check the type of an image. If you have an image `cv::Mat img = cv::imread("someImage.xyz")`, you just do `int theType = img.type()`.

However, as you would expect, calling `img.type()` just gives an integer, an not an enum name (e.g. `CV_32FC1`).

Is there an easy way to print out the enum name (e.g. `CV_32FC1`) if I know the integer value of the OpenCV enum?

Comment: For those who happen to be familiar with CUDA, the OpenCV function that I'm looking for is sort of like the `cudaGetErrorString(int)` function in CUDA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out what type of a Mat object is with Mat::type() in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv)

Comment: voting to close because the other question contains answers that mention `cv::typeToString()`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To my knowledge, such a function doesn't exist in OpenCV.

I think you would be better off writing your own function to get those. A lot of switch cases but I guess it does the job. The enumeration can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#fixed-pixel-types-limited-use-of-templates).

**EDIT:**

This is something you could use to extract the types. I am guessing there could be a more efficient method, but I can't wrap my head around it right now.

```
std::string getImageType(int number)
{
    // find type
    int imgTypeInt = number%8;
    std::string imgTypeString;

    switch (imgTypeInt)
    {
        case 0:
            imgTypeString = "8U";
            break;
        case 1:
            imgTypeString = "8S";
            break;
        case 2:
            imgTypeString = "16U";
            break;
        case 3:
            imgTypeString = "16S";
            break;
        case 4:
            imgTypeString = "32S";
            break;
        case 5:
            imgTypeString = "32F";
            break;
        case 6:
            imgTypeString = "64F";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // find channel
    int channel = (number/8) + 1;

    std::stringstream type;
    type<<"CV_"<<imgTypeString<<"C"<<channel;

    return type.str();
}
```

Comment: Good thinking. I followed your suggestion and wrote some code to do this. See my answer below.

Comment: Rather than using the ints (which were right at the time you checked them on your particular build) you should use the enums themselves. `case 8U: str= "8U"` then you're sure to get them right if the enums change in a different build.

Comment: Hard coding 8 in the code is not a good idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv#comment78963853_17820615

Comment: `cv::typeToString()` makes this obsolete/superfluous

Answer (score 19):

Following @Bob's advice, I wrote my own function to solve this problem. Here it is:

```
// take number image type number (from cv::Mat.type()), get OpenCV's enum string.
string getImgType(int imgTypeInt)
{
    int numImgTypes = 35; // 7 base types, with five channel options each (none or C1, ..., C4)

    int enum_ints[] =       {CV_8U,  CV_8UC1,  CV_8UC2,  CV_8UC3,  CV_8UC4,
                             CV_8S,  CV_8SC1,  CV_8SC2,  CV_8SC3,  CV_8SC4,
                             CV_16U, CV_16UC1, CV_16UC2, CV_16UC3, CV_16UC4,
                             CV_16S, CV_16SC1, CV_16SC2, CV_16SC3, CV_16SC4,
                             CV_32S, CV_32SC1, CV_32SC2, CV_32SC3, CV_32SC4,
                             CV_32F, CV_32FC1, CV_32FC2, CV_32FC3, CV_32FC4,
                             CV_64F, CV_64FC1, CV_64FC2, CV_64FC3, CV_64FC4};

    string enum_strings[] = {"CV_8U",  "CV_8UC1",  "CV_8UC2",  "CV_8UC3",  "CV_8UC4",
                             "CV_8S",  "CV_8SC1",  "CV_8SC2",  "CV_8SC3",  "CV_8SC4",
                             "CV_16U", "CV_16UC1", "CV_16UC2", "CV_16UC3", "CV_16UC4",
                             "CV_16S", "CV_16SC1", "CV_16SC2", "CV_16SC3", "CV_16SC4",
                             "CV_32S", "CV_32SC1", "CV_32SC2", "CV_32SC3", "CV_32SC4",
                             "CV_32F", "CV_32FC1", "CV_32FC2", "CV_32FC3", "CV_32FC4",
                             "CV_64F", "CV_64FC1", "CV_64FC2", "CV_64FC3", "CV_64FC4"};

    for(int i=0; i<numImgTypes; i++)
    {
        if(imgTypeInt == enum_ints[i]) return enum_strings[i];
    }
    return "unknown image type";
}
```

Did I forget to include any OpenCV image types in my lookup table?

Comment: You have to notice two things though. First, there is no case where you have zero channels, there is always at least 1 channel, which actually means that CV_8U = CV_8UC1 etc. And second, you could have up to CV_CN_MAX channels which according to the 2.4.2 documentation is set to 512, so you are limiting yourself to 4 channels this way. I wrote something, see my edit, just make sure to test it cause I didn't compile it.

Comment: @Bob are you sure that the enums for 5 to 512 pixels are implemented? The compiler says that CV_8UC5 is not defined.

Comment: They are not #defined, but they are derived using CV_MAKETYPE, e.g.CV_MAKETYPE(CV_32F, 5); Of course if you don't plan using so many channels, you can use your function, just remove the CV_8U etc cause they return the same result as CV_8UC1 etc

Comment: @Bob Ah, that makes sense. I'm trying to understand all the subtleties of the cv::Mat data structure, so I'm glad you pointed this out.

Comment: `cv::typeToString()` makes this obsolete/superfluous

Answer (score -1):

I'm very late, but a `std::map<int, std::string>` can be cool :)

```
static const std::map<int, std::string> myMap =
{
    {CV_8U , "CV_8U"},
    {CV_8S , "CV_8S"},
    {CV_16U, "CV_16U"},
    {CV_16S, "CV_16S"},
    {CV_32S, "CV_32S"},
    {CV_32F, "CV_32F"},
    {CV_64F, "CV_64F"},
};
```

Then just `std::strcat` the `"C"` and the number of channels if needed.

```
   std::stringstream ss;
   ss<<myMap.at(your_type)<<"C"<<channels;
```

Comment: `cv::typeToString()` makes this obsolete/superfluous

Comment: true, that should be **the answer**