# OpenCV Mat element types and their sizes

Tags: opencv

I'm confused by the OpenCV Mat element types. This is from the docs:

```
There is a limited fixed set of primitive data types the library can operate on.
That is, array elements should have one of the following types:

8-bit unsigned integer (uchar) 
8-bit signed integer (schar)
16-bit unsigned integer (ushort)
16-bit signed integer (short)
32-bit signed integer (int)
32-bit floating-point number (float)
64-bit floating-point number (double)
...

For these basic types, the following enumeration is applied:
enum { CV_8U=0, CV_8S=1, CV_16U=2, CV_16S=3, CV_32S=4, CV_32F=5, CV_64F=6 };
```

It's known that C++ standard doesn't define the size of basic types in bytes, so how do they use such assumptions? And what type should I expect from, let's say, CV_32S, is it int32_t or int?

Comment: types in openCV are quite easy to understand. CV_numbitsType. So CV_16S is a signed integer 16 bits long.

Comment: Then why are they using such names for them in the docs (int, float, etc), while (e.g.) int can be 64 bit instead of 32?

Comment: I don't really know the underlying structure but when you have a mat  created with type CV_32S:
`Mat myMat(10,10,CV_32S);`
you access it with
`myMat.at<int>(1,1) = 1;`

Comment: Btw the table you posted seems to be correct, I mean for each type on the left you use the C++ type in the parentheses to access a mat, as in the comment above.

Comment: @lizarisk 64 int I think is `long long` or `int64`...

Comment: Is there any type of mat where you use `long` type to access the mat elements?

Comment: @Ruchir You should be able to define a [`cv::Mat_<long>`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id7). I doubt you'll be able to apply any of the OpenCV functions to it, though.

Answer (score 9):

Developing from [Miki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32663709/2436175),
In OpenCV 3 definition has moved  to modules/core/include/opencv2/core/**traits.hpp**, where you can find:

```
/** @brief A helper class for cv::DataType

The class is specialized for each fundamental numerical data type supported by OpenCV. It provides
DataDepth<T>::value constant.
*/
template<typename _Tp> class DataDepth
{
public:
    enum
    {
        value = DataType<_Tp>::depth,
        fmt   = DataType<_Tp>::fmt
    };
};



template<int _depth> class TypeDepth
{
    enum { depth = CV_USRTYPE1 };
    typedef void value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_8U>
{
    enum { depth = CV_8U };
    typedef uchar value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_8S>
{
    enum { depth = CV_8S };
    typedef schar value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16U>
{
    enum { depth = CV_16U };
    typedef ushort value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16S>
{
    enum { depth = CV_16S };
    typedef short value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_32S>
{
    enum { depth = CV_32S };
    typedef int value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_32F>
{
    enum { depth = CV_32F };
    typedef float value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_64F>
{
    enum { depth = CV_64F };
    typedef double value_type;
};
```

In *most of the cases/compilers* you should be fine using C++ exact data types. You wouldn't have problems with single byte data types (`CV_8U` -> `uint8_t` and `CV_8U` -> `int8_t`) as [unambiguously defined in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/2436175). The same for [float (32bit) and double (64bit)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Floating_point_types). However, it is true that for other data types to be completely sure you use the correct data type (for example when using the `at<>` method) you should use for example:

```
typedef TypeDepth<CV_WHATEVER_YOU_USED_TO_CREATE_YOUR_MAT>::value_type access_type;
myMat.at<access_type>(y,x) = 0;
```

As a side note, I am surprised they decided to take such an ambiguous approach, instead of simply using exact data types.

Therefore, regarding your last question:

> What type should I expect from, let's say, `CV_32S`?

I believe the most precise answer, in OpenCV 3, is:

```
TypeDepth<CV_32S>::value_type
```

Comment: Great answer thanks.. OpenCV does not follow C++ slandered in most cases. Although it is a fantastic computer vision library, I hate dealing with it in C++. it always brakes my code and makes me to write codes that I feel shame of them.

Comment: How do you access value_type? Your example doesn't work for me in OpenCV 3.0, because it is a member and not public.

Comment: @John: yes, just replace "class" with "struct", then it works. With my OpenCV 2.4.5 version there is no hader, I had to add the code manually to my sources.
Please note Mat::elemSize1() method which also shows size in bytes of one number stored in Mat.

Comment: @karsten You are not going to modify OpenCV headers, are you? Don't do that.

Comment: What if we get `CV_WHATEVER_YOU_USED_TO_CREATE_YOUR_MAT` from the data? If it is not a constant value?

Comment: @MilanJain In that case you might need a case statement based on the return value of [`type()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa6477efc7399fbe742418250ccf99a4b)

Comment: @Antonio: But in that case the complete processing has to be put in switch statement only which could be very inefficient.

Comment: @MilanJain You have to make sure the check is done only once/rarely, so it means indeed it cannot be inside a loop, the condition has to be put outside, and the loop code has to be repeated for each data type. Ideally, you would separate the loop into a function [templated](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) on the data type, so that you might be able to contain code duplication. [Function traits](https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/function-traits/) might be also useful in this case, depending on how specialized have to be the operations based on the data type.

Answer (score 4):

In `core.hpp` you can find the following:

```
/*!
  A helper class for cv::DataType

  The class is specialized for each fundamental numerical data type supported by OpenCV.
  It provides DataDepth<T>::value constant.
*/
template<typename _Tp> class DataDepth {};

template<> class DataDepth<bool> { public: enum { value = CV_8U, fmt=(int)'u' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<uchar> { public: enum { value = CV_8U, fmt=(int)'u' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<schar> { public: enum { value = CV_8S, fmt=(int)'c' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<char> { public: enum { value = CV_8S, fmt=(int)'c' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<ushort> { public: enum { value = CV_16U, fmt=(int)'w' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<short> { public: enum { value = CV_16S, fmt=(int)'s' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<int> { public: enum { value = CV_32S, fmt=(int)'i' }; };
// this is temporary solution to support 32-bit unsigned integers
template<> class DataDepth<unsigned> { public: enum { value = CV_32S, fmt=(int)'i' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<float> { public: enum { value = CV_32F, fmt=(int)'f' }; };
template<> class DataDepth<double> { public: enum { value = CV_64F, fmt=(int)'d' }; };
template<typename _Tp> class DataDepth<_Tp*> { public: enum { value = CV_USRTYPE1, fmt=(int)'r' }; };
```

You can see that `CV_32S` is the value for the type `int`, not `int32_t`.

Answer (score 2):

While C++ doesn't define the size of an element, the question is hypothetical: for systems OpenCV is run on, the sizes are known. Given

```
cv::Mat m(32,32,CV_32SC1, cv:Scalar(0));
std::cout << "size of the element in bytes: " << m.depth() << std::endl;
std::cout << "or " << m.step.p[ m.dims-1 ]/m.channels() << std::endl;
```

So how can you be sure it is `int`?

An attempt to call

```
int pxVal = m.at<int>(0,0);
```

will

```
CV_DbgAssert( elemSize()==sizeof(int) );
```

Where the left hand is defined via the `cv::Mat::flags` -- in this example as the predefined depth of the `CV_32SC1` equal to

```
CV_DbgAssert( m.depth() == sizeof(int) )
```

or

```
CV_DbgAssert( 4 == sizeof(int) )
```

So if you succeeded you are left only the endianness. And that was checked when the cvconfig.h was generated (by CMake).

TL;DR, expect the types given in the header and you'll be fine.

Comment: m.depth() is not in bytes, but delivers EV enum value for type, e.g. CV_8U.

Comment: use elemSize1() instead. Note that elemSize() == elemSize1() * channels()

Answer (score 0):

You can find all definitions on your questions in opencv's sources.

See https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found several #define in OpenCV's code related to CV_8UC1, CV_32SC1, etc. To make the enumerations work, OpenCV put additional codes to convert the plain numbers together as a parameter (i.e, CV_8UC1, CV_16UC2...are all represented by their respective numbers), and break the depth and channels apart in the definition of CvMat(I guess Mat may have similar codes in its definition). Then, it uses create() to allocate spaces for the matrix. Since create() is inline, I can only guess that it is similar to malloc() or something. 
As source codes changes a lot from 2.4.9 to 3.0.0, I need to post more evidence later. Please allow me a little time to find out more and edit my answer.

Answer (score -3):

In short the table you provided is correct.
If you want to directly access a pixel, you typecast it to the specifier to the right, for example CV_32S is a signed 32-bit.
The S always means a signed integral number (signed char, signed short, signed int)
The F always means a floating point number  (float, double)
The U always means an unsigned integral number.

The enumeration is used only when creating or converting a Mat. It's a way of telling the mat which is the desired type, as I understand it it's the C predecessor to when templates were not used.

I use the C functionality exclusively, and in order to create an image, it would be an error to pass the following:

```
cvCreateImage(mySize,char, nChannels);
```

Instead, I pass the following:

```
cvCreateImage(mySize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, nChannels);
```

Here, the IPL_DEPTH_8U is a flag that is used by the function. The function itself has a switch-type statement that checks the flag. The actual value of the flag is most often meaningless as it's most often controlled by conditional, not algebraic statements.

Comment: This is irrelevant. The question is on opencv2 and the answer relates to opencv1