# How to acess pixel values from vector<Point> in a CV_16S in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

i am tring to access the pixel values from an CV_16S-image at positions which are stored in a vector. From an other example (i don't find the link anymore) i found a way to reach this with an `<ptr>`. Unfortunately this example was for an CV_8U-image and because of that my results seem to be wrong. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me the correct way.

```
  Mat src_gray = imread( "b.bmp" , IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
  Mat grad_x;
  Sobel( src_gray, grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );

  std::vector<Point> pointList;
  Point pt;
  pt.x = grad_x.cols;
  pt.y = grad_x.rows;
  pointList.push_back(pt);
  pt.y = 1;
  pointList.push_back(pt);
  float outFloat =  *(grad_x.ptr<float>(pointList[0].y)+pointList[0].x);
```

UPDATE: solved by micka:
    `grad_x.at<short>(pointList[0]);` 
and  `*(grad_x.ptr<short>(pointList[0].y)+pointList[0].x);` give the same results.

Comment: Hi, welcome! What does `grad_x.ptr<float>()` mean? Does it compile? Could you try without the `<float>`? Lastly CV_16S is a signed integer 16 bits long  (`short`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245262/opencv-mat-element-types-and-their-sizes  defined in [traits.hpp](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/df5/core_2include_2opencv2_2core_2traits_8hpp.html). It is not a float.

Comment: grad_x.at<short>(Point(x,y)) would be easiest syntax to access a single point of single channel Mat with type CV_16S(C1). So for example grad_x.at<short>(pointList[0])

Comment: Thank you both, short outFloat = *(grad_x.ptr<short>(pointList[0].y+pointList[0].x) seems to be right. The question is answered. With the simple connection Francis shows (16bit = short) the question seems very stupid afterwards - but thanks again!