# OpenCV C++: Unable to access mat element when mat type is unknown?

Tags: c++, opencv, element, mat

Learning from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37484930/1434693, I created following templates in my header file `MatOperations.h`

```
template<int _depth> class TypeDepth
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_USRTYPE1 };
        typedef void value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_8U>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_8U };
        typedef uchar value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_8S>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_8S };
        typedef schar value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16U>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_16U };
        typedef ushort value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16S>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_16S };
        typedef short value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_32S>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_32S };
        typedef int value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_32F>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_32F };
        typedef float value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_64F>
{
    public:
        enum { depth = CV_64F };
        typedef double value_type;
};
```

Now to access the element of a matrix in `MatOperations.cpp`, I am using following command:

```
int type = gray_image.type();
typedef TypeDepth<type>::value_type access_type;
std::cout << gray_image.at<access_type>(1, 1);
```

However, templates expect a constant value. At this point, I have two questions:

1. How to correct it?
2. Is it the fastest way to access mat element if we are learning type from the data? If not, how can I improve it?

Comment: Although this is not that elegent, but it's useful: `switch(img.depth()){ case CV_8U: break;}`

Comment: @Silencer: I tried doing that but the code has to go through switch case everytime you access a value.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV have its own template traits class names :`DataType` . Yes unlike the class you made the template parameter of `DataType` is the type (`uchar,...,double, cv::Vec2b,... cv::Vec4d`).
You have confuse the method `type()` and `depth()` of a `Mat`. The method `type()` return the type flag i.e. the type AND its channels (e.g. `CV_8UC3`) while the method `depth()` return only the type (e.g. if you are working with a colour image `CV_8U`).

***Is it the fastest way to access mat element if we are learning type from the data? If not, how can I improve it?***

Actually there is several way to do it one that is use in some OpenCV's cuda module such as the *bilateral filter* consist to create a template function that take generic arguments and set some type specific containers and do some work.

e.g.

```
    // Anonymous namespace allow not to put static in from of every function declared in its scope.
        namespace
        {
                // without using specialized container
                template<class type>
                void fma_worker_gen(const cv::Mat& _A, const cv::Mat& _B, const cv::Mat& _C, cv::Mat& _D)
                {
                   for(int r=0;r<A.rows;r++)
                      for(int c=0;c<A.cols;c++)
                          _D.at<type>(r,c) = _A.at<type>(r,c) * _B.at<type>(r,c) + _C.at<type>(r,c);
                }
            // with specialized container. Remember by assignment there is not copy see documentation for more explanation about it.
                template<class type>
                void fma_worker_spec(const cv::Mat& _A, const cv::Mat& _B, const cv::Mat& _C, cv::Mat& _D)
                {

                  cv::Mat_<type> A = _A;
                  cv::Mat_<type> B = _B;
                  cv::Mat_<type> C = _C;
                  cv::Mat_<type> D = _D;

                   for(int r=0;r<A.rows;r++)
                      for(int c=0;c<A.cols;c++)
                          D(r,c) = A(r,c) * B(r,c) + C(r,c);
                }
           } // anonymous namespace


            // callable function.
            void fma(cv::InputArray _A, cv::InputArray _B, cv::InputArray _C, cv::OutputArray _D)
            {
              typedef void(*function_type)(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&);
    // I set fma_worker_gen but fma_worker_spec could also fit.
              static const funcs[7][4] = 
                                       {
                                         {fma_worker_gen<uchar>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec2b>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec3b>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec4b>},
    {fma_worker_gen<schar>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec<schar,2> >, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec<schar,3> >, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec<schar,4> >},
    {fma_worker_gen<ushort>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec2w>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec3w>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec4w>},
    {fma_worker_gen<short>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec2s>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec3s>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec4s>},
    {fma_worker_gen<int>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec2i>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec3i>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec4i>},
    {fma_worker_gen<float>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec2f>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec3f>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec4f>},
    {fma_worker_gen<double>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec2d>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec3d>, fma_worker_gen<cv::Vec4d>},
                                       };
    CV_Assert( (_A.size()==_B.size()) && (_A.size()==_C.size()) && (_A.type()==_B.type()) && (_A.type()==_C.type()) );

   _D.create(_A.size(),_A.type()); // Allocate memory only size or type does not fit the arguments.

   cv::Mat A = _A.getMat();
   cv::Mat B = _B.getMat();
   cv::Mat C = _C.getMat();
   cv::Mat D = _D.getMat();

   function_type fun = nullptr;

   fun = funcs[A.depth()][A.channels()-1];

   CV_Assert(fun);

   fun(A,B,C,D);

            }
```

**Note:** the code above is there as an illustration and may not work nor compile as is.

The approach is interesting in term of memory because you work with your data without converting them.
Actually in the above due to some overflow question you may want to have the matrix D of different type than A,B,C in order.

There is however a much easier way to work with `Mat` elements that consist to cast and reshape the data in order to simplify the processing before reshaping it before returning it.

e.g.

```
void fma(cv::InputArray _A, cv::InputArray _B, cv::InputArray _C, cv::OutputArray _D)
                {
    CV_Assert( (_A.size()==_B.size()) && (_A.size()==_C.size()) && (_A.type()==_B.type()) && (_A.type()==_C.type()) );

   _D.create(_A.size(),_A.type()); // Allocate memory only size or type does not fit the arguments.

   cv::Mat A = _A.getMat();
   cv::Mat B = _B.getMat();
   cv::Mat C = _C.getMat();
   cv::Mat D = _D.getMat();

   const int stype = A.type();
   const int sdepth = CV_MAT_DEPTH(stype);
   const int wdepth = std::max(sdepth,CV_32F);
   const int cn = CV_MAT_CN(stype);
   const int wtype = CV_MAKETYPE(wdepth,cn);

   // now a temporary variable is needed.
   cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(A.size(),wtype);

   // if wdepth != sdepth a copy is make during the conversion nothing happen otherwise.
   A = A.convertTo(A,wdepth);
   B = B.convertTo(B,wdepth);
   C = C.convertTo(C,wdepth);

   // OpenCV's Mat container management the memory as row aligned and the channels are interlaced. This mean that reshaping an matrix with C channels to a matrix with a single channel is unlikely to return a copy.

   A = A.reshape(1);
   B = B.reshape(1);
   C = C.reshape(1);
   tmp = tmp.reshape(1);

   if(wdepth==CV_32F)
   {
     for(int r=0;r<A.rows;r++)
        for(int c=0;c<A.cols;c++)
           tmp.at<float>(r,c) = A.at<float>(r,c)*B.at<float>(r,c)+C.at<float>(r,c);
   }
   else
   {
     for(int r=0;r<A.rows;r++)
        for(int c=0;c<A.cols;c++)
           tmp.at<double>(r,c) = A.at<double>(r,c)*B.at<double>(r,c)+C.at<double>(r,c);
   }
   tmp = tmp.reshape(cn);
   tmp.convertTo(D,sdepth); 

   // Because there is no copy by assignement if the source type (sdepth) and the working type (wdepth) are the same then the fact to reshape the matrix may also have reshape it outside the function. By reshaping every matrix to its original shape any unwilled influence is eliminate.

   if(sdepth == wdepth)
    {
      A = A.reshape(cn);
      B = B.reshape(cn);
      C = C.reshape(cn);
     }
}
```

**Note:** the code above is there as an illustration and may not work nor compile as is.

Using a working type is faster and easier to work with because some priors can be made concerning the types.
The last example the channels are manage in a more implicit way i.e. when the matrices are reshape to one channel (`.reshape(1)`) the number of column is multiply by the number of channels due to the fact that OpenCV store the channels as interlaced.
In some circonstances it may be usefull not to reshape to one channels and work directly with the channels, then you can blend the two approaches.

A last point consist to use prior on your data and/or the working type.
e.g.

```
cv::Mat1s a = {1,2,3,4,5};
cv::Mat1s b = {6,7,8,9,10};
cv::Mat1s c = {11,12,13,14,15};

cv::Mat1f tmp = cv::Mat1f::zeros(a.size()); // or cv::Mat1f tmp = a*b+c;
for(int i=0;i<a.total();i++)
   tmp(i) = a(i)*b(i)+c(i);

cv::Mat1s d = tmp;
```

Comment: this answer is just a mess of useless code. Consider revising it to directly answer the OPs question, please.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a data type from a cv::Mat object's type.

To access unknown-type elements, one approach is to use if/switch statement, just like @Kinght 金 said. You can find similar usage in opencv source codes, for instance, `cv::fitEllipse`:

```cpp
cv::RotatedRect cv::fitEllipse( InputArray _points )
{
    // ...
    bool is_float = depth == CV_32F;
    const Point* ptsi = points.ptr<Point>();
    const Point2f* ptsf = points.ptr<Point2f>();
    // ...
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        Point2f p = is_float ? ptsf[i] : Point2f((float)ptsi[i].x, (float)ptsi[i].y);
        c += p;
    }
    // ...
}
```

The other method is to make your function templated, if you know the type of the cv::Mat in your codes:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void func(const cv::Mat& src)
{
    // ...
    auto val = src.at<T>(row, col);
    // ...
}

func<int>(matrix); // call function with input type CV_32SC1
```

Type declaration as well as template params are evaluated at **compile time** (that's why they must be constant expression, i.e. constexpr), but the type of the cv::Mat passed to your function can only be determined at **runtime** (it may be read from file).

`TypeDepth` in opencv is marked **DEPRECATED** now, and there's no alternative. Maybe opencv developers had found it totally useless.