# how to know the datatype of a loaded/read image in opencv?

Tags: opencv, svm

In my project, i read some images, find their keypoints and compute descriptors. And, then i store these descriptors in another image called featureUnclustered.

**Now, i want to know the "Datatype" (i.e. float / Uchar / int) of this featureUnclustered image.
How can i do so?**

```
Mat input = ("sample.jpg", 1);

Mat descriptor, featureUnclustered;

detector.detect(input, keypoints);
detector.compute(input, keypoints,descriptor); 
featuresUnclustered.push_back(descriptor);
```

How can i know the datatype of "featureUnclustered"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

[Mat::type()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-type) which will returns the type of a matrix element. This is an identifier compatible with the CvMat type system, like CV_16SC3 or 16-bit signed 3-channel array, and so on.

Also see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv)