# cv::Mat , get value at row column without knowing the type of the matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

so I am trying to get the value of a matrix, which type I do not know, using row and column value. I basically want to implement the following:

```
bool someFunction(cv::Mat m){
   return m(1,0) != 0;
}
```

I know this will error out since I need to specify the type like so **m.at< Type >(1,0)**
but I would not know the type.

I tried doing the following:  **m.at< m.type() >(1,0)** but that, of course, errors out.

I am wondering what could potentially work here. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know the type of the element, how do you know that comparing the element to a number (0) is a legal / reasonable operation?

Answer (score 1):

A not so elegant solution. Use [depth](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) and a switch case.

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<stdint.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

bool someFunction(Mat m) {
    switch (m.depth()){
        case CV_8U:
            return m.at<uint8_t>(1,0) != 0;
        case CV_8S:
            return m.at<int>(1,0) != 0;
        case CV_16U:
            return m.at<uint16_t>(1,0) != 0;
        case CV_16S:
            return m.at<int16_t>(1,0) != 0;
        case CV_32S:
            return m.at<int32_t>(1,0) != 0;
        case CV_32F:
            return m.at<float>(1,0) != 0;
        case CV_64F:
            return m.at<double>(1,0) != 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    Mat m(2,2, CV_8UC1);
    cout << someFunction(m) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are doing this for single channel images, but you will get an idea even for > 1 channel images.

You can change your function to

```
template<class T>
bool someFunction(cv::Mat_<T> m) {
   return m(1,0) != 0;
};
```

And you can call the function like -

```
someFunction<uchar>(gray);
```

Here, I am assuming that you know the type, from the function you are calling.
In place of `uchar`, you can use any data type your *Mat* object is of.
If you want to automate this task also, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv).

Comment: The question specifically says that the type of Mat is not known.