# not correct print with unchar Mat for image 8UC1 c++

Tags: c++, opencv, short, unsigned-char

Could help somebody please ?
I have an image after Canny detector, the type is 8UC1, when i want to access to the values, cout gives to me ? (Test Canny�), so my code is following:

```
Mat src;

/// Load an image
src = imread( argv[1] );

if( !src.data )
{ return -1; }

Mat src_gray(src.size[1],src.size[2],CV_8U,0);
```

//some parameters

```
int edgeThresh = 1;
//int lowThreshold;
int lowThreshold = 100;
int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
int ratio = 3;
int kernel_size = 3;
//char* window_name = "Edge Map";

  cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  Mat detected_edges;
  /// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
  blur( src_gray, detected_edges, Size(3,3) );


  ///Canny edge detection
  Canny( detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );


  for (unsigned int i=0;i<detected_edges.size[1];i++){
    for  (unsigned int j=0;j<detected_edges.size[1];j++) {
        if (detected_edges.at<unsigned char>(i,j)!=0)
            cout<<"Test Canny"<<detected_edges.at<unsigned char>(i,j)<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I change in short, i.e. (i,j), it gives to me value between -256 and 255.
I do not understand why with the type 8UC1, i need to use short and is it correct to use short ?
(To verify surely which type I have, I used this link [How to find out what type of a Mat object is with Mat::type() in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv))
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly, I found the answer, because uchar has some problems with cout, so i need to write 
std::cout<<"Test Canny"<<(int)detected_edges.at(i,j)<