# OpenCV video stabilization

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm trying to implement video stabilization using OpenCV videostab module. I need to do it in stream, so I'm trying to get motion between two frames. After learning documentation, I decide to do it this way:

```
estimator = new cv::videostab::MotionEstimatorRansacL2(cv::videostab::MM_TRANSLATION);
keypointEstimator = new cv::videostab::KeypointBasedMotionEstimator(estimator);

bool res;
auto motion = keypointEstimator->estimate(this->firstFrame, thisFrame, &res);
std::vector<float> matrix(motion.data, motion.data + (motion.rows*motion.cols));
```

Where `firstFrame` and `thisFrame` are fully initialized frames. The problem is, that `estimate` method always return the matrix like that:

[image: a busy cat]

In this matrix only last value(`matrix[8]`) is changing from frame to frame. Am I correctly use videostab objects and how can I apply this matrix on frame to get result?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to OpenCV but here is how I have solved this issue.
The problem lies in the line:

```
std::vector<float> matrix(motion.data, motion.data + (motion.rows*motion.cols));
```

For me, the `motion` matrix is of type `64-bit double` (check yours from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv)) and copying it into `std::vector<float> matrix` of type `32-bit float` messes-up the values.
To solve this issue, try replacing above line with:

```
std::vector<float> matrix;
for (auto row = 0; row < motion.rows; row++) {
    for (auto col = 0; col < motion.cols; col++) {
            matrix.push_back(motion.at<float>(row, col));
    }
}
```

I have tested it with running the `estimator` on duplicate set of points and it gives expected results with most entries close to `0.0` and `matrix[0], matrix[4] and matrix[8]` being `1.0` (using author's code with this setting was giving the same erroneous values as author's picture displays).