# Accessing elements of cv::Mat OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to apply derivative based color constancy on images and I'm using opencv in c++ to do so.
I'm using Sobel derivatives to calculate my gradients but I don't know what I should cast pixel values of gradient image to in order to be able to read and change them.

```
Sobel( gradr1, gradr1, gradr1.depth(), 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
gradr1.at<char>(i,j)
```

What should I use instead of char?

Comment: what's gradr1.depth()? correct sobel (and tutorial) uses CV_16U or CV_32F typically which would be unsigned short or float.

Comment: and if you are in doubt, call gradr1.type() after Sobel computation and compare it to the standard opencv types like CV_8UC1, CV_16UC1, CV_32FC1, CV_64FC1, etc.

Comment: get user readable opencv types with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv/17820615#17820615