# OpneCV - convolution with decimal remained

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a C++ implement of Felzenszwalb segmentation algorithm and now I am in trouble with the Gaussian convolution. What I need is a convolution which keeps precision after decimal but so far, the program still seems to cut away numbers after points even if the `Mat` was converted to `float`. Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc != 3) {
    std::cout << "Usage: ./a.out image sigma ..." << std::endl;
    return -1;
  } 
  double sigma = std::stod(argv[2]);
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1], cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
  cv::Mat f_image;
  cv::Mat f_filtered;
  image.convertTo(f_image, CV_32FC3);
  // cv::GaussianBlur(f_image, f_filtered, cv::Size(9, 9), sigma);
  cv::Mat kernel_1D = cv::getGaussianKernel(9, sigma);
  cv::sepFilter2D(f_image, f_filtered, -1, kernel_1D, kernel_1D);

  std::cout << f_filtered.type() << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i != f_filtered.rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j != f_filtered.cols; ++j) {
      std::cout << f_filtered.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j) << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

My first try was use `cv::GaussianBlur` directly (which was commented out above), although the type of `f_filtered` was `21` (from [this table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39780825/5105207) it should be a 32 bit float) but the following loop output something like

```
21
...
[137, 231, 66]
[154, 231, 248]
[65, 10, 102]
[62, 65, 101]
[201, 228, 66]
[91, 136, 246]
[65, 119, 226]
[66, 65, 249]
[185, 229, 66]
[120, 233, 238]
[65, 137, 40]
[79, 65, 100]
[174, 234, 66]
[78, 194, 219]
[65, 136, 198]
[96, 65, 152]
[87, 245, 66]
[23, 101, 193]
...
```

And I do not really believe these are float numbers as there is not any decimal points. And after that I use `cv::sepFilter2D` with `cv::getGaussianKernel` but the result seems to be same. Another thing that convince me there are problems on data types as I have previously implemented this algorithm with Python. At that time I got into a quite similar trouble and I solved by converting data to float (`img = img.astype(np.float)`) before (`img = cv2.filter2D(img, ddepth=-1, kernel=gaussain_kernel)`). But this time type convert seems will not change result precision and I do not know what to do. So, any suggestions?

Comment: You using 3 channels in the Mat, try `f_filtered.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, j)[0]` in the cout for first channel.

Comment: Indeed, without changing the part @seccpur mentioned you probably just get some random numbers because your program is reading now the wrong parts of the physical memory.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Sorry, I do not understand that very much. I have feed `f_filtered` into `sepFiltered2D` function as `dst`, why will it read wrong parts.

Comment: Hi, @seccpur, It suddenly struck me that I need to call later in the algorithm `cv::norm(_I(i, j), _I(i + 1, j))` where `_I` was defined by `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> _I = f_filtered;`. As there is no `[0]` behind, I wonder will this also cut away numbers after points? If that is the case, could you explain why this truncating take place? Thanks.

Comment: @PageDavid because a float number takes up more space in memory than a char number (usually four times as many bytes). Although this depends on your system, compiler and optimization settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay David, Everything is OK with your code.

You just need to print our outcome with an appropriate type:
std::cout << f_filtered.at<**Vec3f** >(i, j) << std::endl;

I would recommend you to use [Image Watch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.ImageWatch2017) plugin which shows you in debug time the image and all of its metadata (type, channels, etc).

Comment: Everything worked fine after I switch `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3b> _I = f_filtered;` to `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3f> _I = f_filtered;`. Thank you for your help and suggestion.