# OpenCV - How to convert grayscale to color (CV_8UC3)?

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, type-conversion

I am trying to add two Mat objects together, but I am facing an error.

This is the working code:

```c
    Mat src1, src2, dst;

    /// Read image ( same size, same type )
    src1 = imread("lion.png");
    src2 = imread("bluebell.png");

    dst = src1 + 0.5 * src2;

    imshow("Blend", dst);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

Both `src1` and `src2` have the same type which is `CV_8UC3`. But when I try this:

```c
    Mat src1, src2, src3, dst;

    /// Read image
    src1 = imread("lion.png");
    src2 = imread("bluebell.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    src2.convertTo(src3, COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

    cout << "src1.type " << src1.type() << endl;
    cout << "src2.type " << src2.type() << endl;
    cout << "src3.type " << src3.type() << endl;

    dst = src1 + 0.5 * src3;

    imshow("Blend", dst);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

It doesn't work. Because `src2` and `src3` both have type `0` which is `CV_8U`. But I want `src3` to have type `16` which is `CV_8UC3` (according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39780825/6129428)). This code brings this error:

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::arithm_op

How can I convert a grayscale image to a colored one with exact type of `CV_8UC3`?

Comment: A grayscale image contains no colour information. How would you know what colour to map to what gray tone?

Comment: @JesperJuhl this is true. But I want `src3` to be `CV_8UC3` so that it can be added with `src1`. Even when I initialize `src3` to `CV_8UC3` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change number of channels by calling `convertTo`. According to [reference](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adf88c60c5b4980e05bb556080916978b):

> desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth since **the number of**
>   **channels are the same as the input has**; if rtype is negative, the
>   output matrix will have the same type as the input.

When you have matrix with one channel in grayscale, you can use `cv::merge` to create 3 channels image by putting this one component for BGR channels in new matrix:

```
src1 = imread("lion.png");
src2 = imread("bluebell.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);    // one channel

cv::merge(std::vector<cv::Mat>{src2, src2, src2}, src2);
                            // blue, green,red    as output 3-channels mat
dst = src1 + 0.5 * src2;
```

By calling `convertTo`, you can convert data type of storing values, for example from integer to float.

Comment: Or you just use [`cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab): `cv::cvtColor(src2, src2, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);`.