# cv::Mat to std::string serialization and deserialization giving faulty result

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I try the code below to serialize and deserialize a cv::Mat object. It just records all the uchars into a ostringstream then converts it to string to serialize. Then I deserialize this string using istringstream and save all the uchars into a Mat object. Mat type CV_8UC3 is legit, I checked it by using the function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv) answer. 8UC3 is the channel of the test Mat I give as parameter. I know this is probably a lame way to serialize, so I'm open to better ideas. Anyway the I only get 25 % ish part of the picture. The rest is missing. And I get a weird color distortion in the middle. Output and input images are below the code. If you need anymore details feel free to ask.

```
void dbop::serializeMat(cv::Mat operand) {

std::ostringstream srlzstrstream;
srlzstrstream << operand.rows << " " << operand.cols << " " ;
for(int i = 0; i < operand.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < operand.cols; j++)
        srlzstrstream << operand.at<uchar>(i, j);

std::string srlzdstr = srlzstrstream.str();

uchar uchoper;
int row, col;
std::istringstream desrlzstrstream(srlzdstr);

desrlzstrstream >> row;
desrlzstrstream >> col;
cv::Mat matoper(row, col, CV_8UC3);

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        desrlzstrstream>> uchoper;
        matoper.at<uchar>(i, j) = uchoper;
    }
}

return;
}
```

[This is the input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKgHP.jpg)

[This is the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il6qR.png)

### EDIT

rafix07 after following your advice I found an alternative way that has 3 bytes per pixel. Now I get the complete picture but color distortion (or whatever it is called) is now worse then ever. Top 10% ish of the output image is fine but below that it goes to hell. See the image below code.

```
void dbop::serializeMat(cv::Mat operand) {
std::ostringstream srlzstrstream;
cv::uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)operand.data;
int cn = operand.channels();
cv::Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;

srlzstrstream << operand.rows << " " << operand.cols << " ";
for (int i = 0; i < operand.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < operand.cols; j++) {
        bgrPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i * operand.cols * cn + j * cn + 0]; // B
        bgrPixel.val[1] = pixelPtr[i * operand.cols * cn + j * cn + 1]; // G
        bgrPixel.val[2] = pixelPtr[i * operand.cols * cn + j * cn + 2]; // R
        srlzstrstream << bgrPixel.val[0] << bgrPixel.val[1] << bgrPixel.val[2];
    }
}
std::string srlzdstr = srlzstrstream.str();
uchar uchoper1, uchoper2, uchoper3;
int row, col;
std::istringstream desrlzstrstream(srlzdstr);

desrlzstrstream >> row;
desrlzstrstream >> col;
cv::Mat matoper(row, col, CV_8UC3);

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    cv::Vec3b* ptr = matoper.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        desrlzstrstream >> uchoper1;
        desrlzstrstream >> uchoper2;
        desrlzstrstream >> uchoper3;
        ptr[j] = cv::Vec3b(uchoper1, uchoper2, uchoper3);
    }
}
return;
}
```

[Output image after edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAddP.png)

Comment: You write only one byte from input color image? Your output is CV_8UC3, 3 channels. It doesn't match each other.

Comment: @rafix07 You are right, after your suggestion I found a better way that represents 3 byte per pixel but problem is different now. Check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
uchar ch = 10;
ostringstream os;
os << ch;
```

when you do:

```
std::cout << "[" << os.str() << "]" << std::endl;
```

you will see:

```
[
]
```

because `ostringstream` treats all values stored in (unsigned) `char` as characters (in above case, `10` represents newline, and this newline character is put into stream instead of its numeric value). You have to write / read integers with at least 16 bits precision. And the other issue, when pushing into the stream you have to add whitespaces between values.

So, first update is:

```
srlzstrstream << (int)bgrPixel.val[0] << " " << (int)bgrPixel.val[1] << " " << (int)bgrPixel.val[2] << " ";
```

and the next one:

```
uint16_t uchoper1, uchoper2, uchoper3;
```

Comment: Yes that exactly solved it. I thought casting them to something else would cause data loss or whatever but I guess I was just wrong. :D Thanks man!