# Getting exception while calculating PSNR

Tags: opencv

I have a very simple code to calculate PSNR, when I run it I am getting an exception.

```
void psnr()
{
    try
    {
        Mat img = imread("TestImage.png");
        Mat imgGray, imgCanny;

        Canny(img, imgCanny, 15, 150);

        cout << endl << "PSNR " << cv::PSNR(img, imgCanny);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "Error " << ex.msg;
    }

    waitKey(0);    
}
```

I am getting expection:

> Error OpenCV(4.5.2)
> C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\norm.cpp:1279:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) _src1.type() == _src2.type() in
> function 'cv::PSNR'

What could be the reason for the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that `img` format is 3 channels BGR format and `imgCanny` is single channel (Grayscale format).

The assertion message says:

> (-215:Assertion failed) _src1.type() == _src2.type()

The meaning is that the type of `_src1` and the type of `_src2` are not the same.
When `cv::PSNR` expects the type of the input images to be the same.

For getting the Mat type read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167534/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-a-mat-object-is-with-mattype-in-opencv).

---

A simple solution is converting `img` to Grayscale format:

```
cv::Mat grayImg;
cv::cvtColor(img, grayImg, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cout << endl << "PSNR " << cv::PSNR(grayImg, imgCanny);
```

Comment: Got your point, and the code worked as expected. Thanks.